# Automated Python Script to Notify When two tables do not match with the "Master" Table

Tags: python, sql

There exist three SQL tables. One is the "master" which contains the contents of two other tables which I am using. These two tables differ in their columns. The master list gets updated every day with possible new information but the other two do not. The master table is on a different database than the other two tables.

I need to build a python script that runs every day and notifies people via email when there is a non-match between the master and either one of the two other table's columns of rows.

I have sliced, and created dataframes for each column to then merge onto the master but I am completely at a loss for how to proceed from here. Im a beginner so I may have bitten off more than I can chew and any help would be so appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import numpy as np

## Connect to databases. 

sql_conn1=pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};" "SERVER=servername;" "DATABASE=database;" "trusted_connection=yes;")

sql_conn2=pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};" "SERVER=servername;" "DATABASE=database;" "trusted_connection=yes;")


## Query the table1 data and create a dataframe  

query1 = "SELECT [BN] ,  [BC],  [Id],  [SC] \
    FROM [database].[dbo].[table1]"
df1=pd.read_sql(query1, sql_conn1)

# query for table2
query2 = "SELECT [RMF] ,  [AC],  [AEC],  [AECId] \
    FROM [database].[dbo].[table2]"

df2=pd.read_sql(query2, sql_conn1)

## Create df3 for master table. 

query3 = " SELECT [BN] ,  [BC],  [Id],  [SC],  [RMF] ,\
    [AC], [AEC],  [AECId] FROM [database].[dbo].[master]"
df3 = pd.read_sql(query3, sql_conn1)
```

Thank you